# Do I need to enter the iPhone passcode before apps run automatically?

Tags: ios, startup, restart

I have written an app that automatically restarts on a Significant Location Change if it was closed.

When the device is first powered on, I have configured the device settings to insist on entering the passcode before using the device.
I can't seem to get my app to run if I haven't entered in the passcode.

So: Is there some documentation that says I *must* enter the passcode before running apps - or is there some obscure setting in the application that needs to be made?

I have spent a huge amount of time trying to find information one way or the other in Apple's documentation, but cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the passcode is needed before any apps are restarted into the background.

> If an iOS device with a passcode lock is restarted, no application can launch in the background prior to the device first being unlocked.
>   This behavior, and resulting limitations, are by design.

[Source: Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) late Febrary 2016]